# Change reference's alignment

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

how can I eliminate the indent in the second row of a reference? This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mutavel}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{100} % 100 is a random guess of the total number of references

\bibitem{Stamatelos2020}Stamatelos, D. Towards the Design of a Multispar Composite Wing  [Текст] / D. Stamatelos, G. Labeas // Computation. – 2020, Т.8, №24. – 14с.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

What I get is:

[image]

This is what I need:

[image]

Comment: You do not want to use a .bib file instead?

Comment: No, I already have so many problems using it.

Comment: What is `mutavel`? Which problems do you have with .bib files? Because .bib files are the right way to go.

Comment: `mutavel` is the style used in my university. The problem with .bib files its that I can't personalize the style of the references. I tried also with bibulous but I'm not have really much time to master it. Thats why I prefered to do in this way.

Comment: Ok. when you post an example on this website, it should be compilable: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/371 The mutavel package does not seem to be critical here?

Comment: Not, isn't really. Just for the russian word Текст that could be easily changed for any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Latex, the bibliography in encapsulated in a list environment. The look of the bibliographic entries can thus be formatted via the list environment features as highlighted below

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

@book{Stamatelos2020,
  author    = {Stamatelos, D.},
  title     = {Towards the Design of a Multispar Composite Wing},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = {2020},
  number    = {24},
  volume    = {8},
  note      = {14c}
}

@book{test1,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach,
               Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}  

@article{zunite2009,
    title = {Iterative deconvolution and semiblind deconvolution methods in magnetic archaeological prospecting},
    volume = {74},
    issn = {0016-8033, 1942-2156},
    doi = {10.1190/1.3129263},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2014-01-24},
    journal = {GEOPHYSICS},
    author = {Zunino, Andrea and Benvenuto, Federico and Armadillo, Egidio and Bertero, Mario and Bozzo, Emanuele},
    month = jul,
    year = {2009},
    pages = {L43--L51}
}
\end{filecontents}


\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
      {\section*{\refname}%
       \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
       \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
            {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \setlength{\itemindent}{1.5\leftmargin} %NEW
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\z@}               %NEW
             \leftmargin\z@                         %NEW
             %\advance\leftmargin\labelsep          %NEW
             \@openbib@code
             \usecounter{enumiv}%
             \let\p@enumiv\@empty
             \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       \sloppy
       \clubpenalty4000
       \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
       \widowpenalty4000%
       \sfcode`\.\@m}
      {\def\@noitemerr
        {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
       \endlist}
\makeatother

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help!